# Android webview vs. imageview performance to display images

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-imageview, android-volley

I have searched a lot, but never found the right answer.

Which way is better/faster to display small or big images?

Answer (score 4):

This may not directly answer your question, but have you tried using Volley's [`NetworkImageView`](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java) class ?

Recently, I used [`Volley`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) in a large project to display images, and it was faster and more stable than anything I've seen before. Volley is a networking library for Android developed by the good guys at Google, and it includes image downloading out of the box. It handles small or large images with ease. All you need to do is add the Volley library to your project and replace `ImageView` in your XML layout with `com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView`.

Add the following variables to your `Activity` class:

```
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
```

Create the objects in the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity`:

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);

    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mCache.put(url, bitmap);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return mCache.get(url);
    }
});
```

Then download the image the `getView()` method of your `Adapter` class:

```
NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageUrl("http://somerandomurl.com/somerandomimage.png",mImageLoader);
```

In production code, you would use a global instance of both the `RequestQueue` and `ImageLoader` classes, and your `onCreate()` method wouldn't be cluttered as it is here.

I wouldn't use a `WebView` to display images, though of course it can be done. If you really want to see which way is "faster", you can try out `ImageView`, `NetworkImageView` and `WebView` to load a large image and get a rough time estimate with the `System.nanoTime()` method.

Comment: Good summary. I'd just add that the WebView will also use more memory compared to an ImageView.